# UISlider fixed position

Tags: ios, uislider

I've set a UISlider value to 20 with a scale from MIN 0 to Max 100.

Is there a way to prevent the Slider from going below those initial 20?

Here is a picture to demonstrate what I want to achieve:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/251368/bsp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup an action that handles changes to the slider's value. If the new value is less than 20 then reset the slider's value back to 20.

Add an action:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderUpdate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Handle the change:

```
- (void)sliderUpdate:(UISlider *)slider {
    CGFloat value = slider.value;
    if (value < 20) {
        slider.value = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy! That code only stop the UISlider from going below 20%. But the UILabel which shows me the slider.value still goes down to 0% but it is also supposed to stop at 20%. Any Idea how I can manage that?